# How to remove "Google Docs", "Google Sheets" and "Google Slides" from windows explorer "New" menu?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, context-menu, google-drive

I recently installed **Google Drive** on my **Windows 8** laptop. After installing this disk, 3 items appeared in the "New" menu item in the explorer. Each of the new items leads to a browser with an open page of google documents, tables or slides.

You can see these three elements in the picture:

context menu screenshot

[image].

Using the `CCleaner` utility, I disabled all the context menu items from Google, but the items in the "New" submenu are still there. I could not find the necessary section in the registry on my own. Programs like `nirsoft`'s `ShellMenuNew` also don't see Google items.

**Is it possible to remove these "New" menu items without deleting Google Drive?**

**If is, how can I do it?**

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stumbling upon this, unfortunately none of the solutions mentioned in this thread works for permanent removal. Because if you're running the Google Drive desktop program (which I assume you do, as it's its main function), it will rewrite the `ShellNew -> command` you've removed.

And it will do it in less than a minute, and correct it if you've purposefully changed it so it's not valid, and generally it seems like this program's devs really, *really* didn't want *anyone* removing those entries for *whatever reason, ever*. It's kinda remarkable that they implemented such zealous checks for the removal of those entries, and it's not even the program's main functionality.

Anyway, there's a solution described here, in Microsoft's Tech Community forums:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10/remove-google-sheets-docs-slides-entries-from-quot-new-quot/m-p/3093350

It entails changing the permissions of those cursed `ShellNew-command` registry entries to read-only, so Google Drive can't rewrite them. Unfortunately it leads to Google Drive going into a futile cycle of checking the values and failing to rewrite them, which happens like every minute or so, and so you get that explorer-and-desktop-icons-refresh effect, which is annoying. And generally I don't know how it affects Google Drive and Windows performance, so it really doesn't feel like it's worth the fuss.

So whatever, I just let those entries be. *Congratulations Google Drive's devs, you win.*

Answer (score 2):

**It's not possible.** Each time you delete the registry value responsible for these items (manually or with software), the google drive software will replace it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Remove user permissions from these 3 registries. It wouldn't delete them at least hide them.

- Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.gdoc
- Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.gsheet
- Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.gslides

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try checking with [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns), an official Microsoft tool.

Click on the Explorer tab and you might find Google's entries. Just uncheck the unneeded and the problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google has changed some registry names, so you should delete User(your name) permission from those registries.

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\GoogleDriveFS.gdoc
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\GoogleDriveFS.gsheet
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\GoogleDriveFS.gslides
```